# How to put different host entries on same linux server, for different virtual hosts?

Tags: php, linux, apache, vhosts

The setup is :
Two applications are hosted on same linux server using vhost entries in apache configuration. say :

http://greatapp.example.com

and

http://superapp.example.com

Both of them have a functionality where they do server side http request to a third url  (using php cURL / file_get_contents) :

http://apis.example.com

Now there is a host entry of an in the hosts file '/etc/hosts'

```
xx.xx.xx.xx       apis.example.com
```

This is only intended for greatapp.example.com code, and not for superapp.example.com.

How to configure the server such that **greatapps.example.com** uses the host entry,
but **superapp.example.com** uses the public ip of **apis.example.com**

Comment: You can check out this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357117/virtual-host-not-working-on-xampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done directly:  host name space is global per host.

You could run one of the apaches in a virtual machine with a different `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Each of my apps will have a config file that will be read. That config file can specify what url to use. You can use existing libraries to read config files. In this example I will use Zend_Config_Ini. Here's what your config file can look like for great app:

> [settings]
>
> urls.third_party = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'

This is one is for superapp

> [settings]
>
> urls.third_party = 'http://apis.example.com'

2.Read the url from a config file using Zend_Config_Ini for example:

```
require_once 'Zend/Config/Ini.php';
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('application.ini', 'settings');
$app_config = $config->toArray();

$third_party_url = $app_config['urls']['third_party'];
```

I think you're more flexible this way as you can easily change the url in the config file of the app concerned easily.